# Embedding a web browser in a java application on Mac OS X

Tags: java, cross-browser

I'm developing a cross-platform desktop application using Java. My application requires displaying a couple of websites from within my application and not to open them in any full fledged web browser like Safari or Firefox. I've found some Java libraries and projects for accomplishing this for Windows like [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/), [JDIC for Processing](http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/2008/09/06/multiple-jdic-browsers-in-processing-sketch/) and [Lobo Browser]. But most don't support Mac OS X or maybe I can't figure out how to run them on a Mac. I managed to run Lobo Browser as a simple frame and load a page, but the project is about 2 years old and doesn't render pages properly.
Please suggest if there is any cross-platform library available for embedding a web browser in a java program or even mac only library would do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/), a java API for the Qt toolkit, specifically the [WebKit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtjambi-4.4/html/index.html) package. Full DOM rendering with or without a GUI.